# Multiple filters ensuring non-empty rows

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I wrote a code that applies various filters ('a','b', and 'c') that may result into an empty dataframe. If empty rows is true, then filters must be dropped one-by-one (from 'c' to 'a') until finding a non-empty dataframe. Can someone write that code below more elegantly? The code is:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10]) %>% mutate(c= str_c(a,b))

a.selected <- 1:5
b.selected <- letters[2:5]
c.selected <- c('10j')

filtered <- df %>% 
  filter(a %in% a.selected &
           b %in% b.selected & 
           c %in% c.selected)

if(nrow(filtered)==0) {
  
  filtered1 <- df %>% 
    filter(a %in% a.selected &
             b %in% b.selected)
  filtered <- filtered1
  
} else {
  
  if(nrow(filtered1)==0) {
    
    filtered2 <- df %>% 
      filter(a %in% a.selected)
    filtered <- filtered2
    
  } else {
    
    if(nrow(filtered2)==0) {
      
      filtered3 <- df
      filtered <- filtered3
      
    }
  }
}

filtered

  a b  c
1 2 b 2b
2 3 c 3c
3 4 d 4d
4 5 e 5e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's elegant, but this is considerably shorter:

```r
selections <- list(a.selected, b.selected, c.selected)
combos <- Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, df, selections), accumulate = TRUE)

df %>% 
  filter(combos[[max(which(sapply(combos, any)))]])
#>   a b  c
#> 1 2 b 2b
#> 2 3 c 3c
#> 3 4 d 4d
#> 4 5 e 5e
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(ind = across(everything(), 
    ~ .x %in% get(str_c(cur_column(), ".selected"))) %>% 
         accumulate(`&`) %>% 
         keep(any) %>% 
         tail(1) %>% 
         names) %>% 
  filter(cur_data()[[first(ind)]] %in% get(str_c(first(ind), ".selected"))) %>% 
  select(-ind)
  a b  c
1 2 b 2b
2 3 c 3c
3 4 d 4d
4 5 e 5e
```